# Contest Hall Preparation a20j runtime error

Tags: python, runtime-error

A2oj.com, Runtime Error
Problem #22

Recently I was solving the following problem from a2oj.

https://a2oj.com/p?ID=22

My solution to the problem is:

```
# to check for adjacent items in a 2d array
# just check the item next to it, below it and diagonal to it

t = int(input())
o = []
while t >= 1:
    n,m = map(int,input().split())
    c = 0
    li = []
    uni = []
    while c < m:
        li.append(map(int,input().split()))
        c += 1
    r = 0
    co = 0
    while r < n-1:
        c = 0
        while c < m-1:

            # if the place is empty skip checking
            if li[r][c] == -1:
                c += 1
                continue

            # if university is already counted also skip checking it
            if li[r][c] in uni:
                c += 1
                continue

            if li[r][c] == li[r][c+1]:
                uni.append(li[r][c])
                co += 1

            if li[r][c] == li[r+1][c+1]:
                uni.append(li[r][c])
                co += 1

            if li[r][c] == li[r+1][c]:
                uni.append(li[r][c])
                co += 1


            c += 1
        r += 1
    o.append(co)
    t -= 1

for w in o:
    print(w)
```

This code works perfectly for the given examples. But when I submit it to the a2oj online judges I get Runtime Error. I also can't know why am I getting the error. Can you tell me how can I know the error in a2oj platform or can you help me with the code